# Print distinct from the Array Stream in Java 8

Tags: java-8

How to print the `distinct` element from the Array Stream in `java 8`?

I am playing with `Java-8` and trying to understand how it works with `distinct`.

```
Collection<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C");

// Get collection without duplicate i.e. distinct only
List<String> distinctElements = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

//Let's verify distinct elements
System.out.println(distinctElements);

// Array Stream
System.out.println("------------------------------");
int[] numbers = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 2,3};
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(numbers).sum()); // ==> Sum
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(numbers).count()); // ==> Count
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(numbers).distinct()); // ==> Distinct
```

The last line Just merely gives me reference of object, I want actual values

```
[A, B, C, D]
------------------------------
46
8
java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$4@2d98a335
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't see distinct values directly because [`IntStream.distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#distinct--) is not a terminal operation and it returns `IntStream` as stated in the documentation:

> Returns a stream consisting of the distinct elements of this stream.

You have to terminate your stream, similarly to code you already have in your example:

```
List<String> distinctElements = list.stream()
        .distinct()
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here you call [`Stream.collect(Collector<? super T,A,R> collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) method which is a terminal operation and you get a list of distinct elements in return.

Both [`Stream.count()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) and [`IntStream.sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--) are terminal operations and they perform calculation right away, closing your stream and returning a value.

Comment: I am talking about the Array Stream

Comment: @Prateek `Arrays.stream(numbers)` returns `Stream<T>` object.

Comment: Hey, we can't directly used Arrays.stream(numbers)
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());, please see error shown in the below comments

Comment: @Prateek you have to use `.boxed()` before collecting to switch from `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>` and it will work.

Comment: To catch up to the question’s code which just wants to print it, you can do without boxing: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.stream(numbers).distinct().toArray()));`

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.stream()` normally returns a `Stream`, but it has an overloaded version: `stream(int[] array)`, which returns an `IntStream`, which is a stream of primitive ints. `IntStream.distinct()` returns an `IntStream` as well.

In order to collect it, you could use `collect(Collectors.toList())`:

```
Arrays.stream(numbers)
    .distinct()
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You could also store the result into an `int[]`:

```
Arrays.stream(numbers)
    .distinct()
    .toArray();
```

Comment: I dont think so we can do above:
Multiple markers at this line
 - The method collect(Supplier<R>, ObjIntConsumer<R>, BiConsumer<R,R>) in the type IntStream is not applicable for the arguments 
  (Collector<Object,?,List<Object>>)
 - Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collector<Object,capture#5-of ?,List<Object>> to Supplier<R>

Comment: @Prateek I see, you must first convert it to a `Stream`. It can be done with the `boxed()` method.